# Trying to add the result of a QGeoSearchReply to a maps::DataProvider in Blackberry 10 Cascades (C++, QT & QML)

Tags: c++, qt, maps, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am trying to add the result of a QGeoSearchReply to a maps :: DataProvider, and have found a function called convertToGeoList at [this site](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__platform__geo.html), and am trying to use it, but the documentation doesn't even tell me what class the function is part of - as the geo class itself doesn't seem to exist in Blackberry Cascades. Anyway - here is code I have come up with:

```
void Mapper::mapSearchResults(QtMobilitySubset::QGeoSearchReply *reply)

{

    disconnect(mapSearchManagerEngine_, SIGNAL(finished(QtMobilitySubset::QGeoSearchReply*)),
        this, SLOT(mapSearchResults(QMobilitySubset::QGeoSearchReply*)));
    maps :: DataProvider provider;
    provider.add(bb :: platform::geo::convertToGeoList(reply->places()));
    maps::MapData mapData;
    mapData.addProvider(&provider);
    mapView_->setMapData(&mapData);

}
```

But I end up with this error: error: 'convertToGeoList' is not a member of 'bb :: platform::geo'-

Could someone please clarify how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are right: `bb::platform::geo` is not a class. It's a namespace. Regarding [`convertToGeoList()`](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__platform__geo.html#function-converttogeolist-src), it's defined in `bb/platform/geo/geo_converters.hpp`. Including it should fix your error:

```
bb/platform/geo/geo_converters.hpp
106:BB_PLATFORM_GEO_EXPORT bb::platform::geo::GeoList convertToGeoList( const QList src );
122:BB_PLATFORM_GEO_EXPORT bb::platform::geo::GeoList convertToGeoList( const QtMobilitySubset::QGeoSearchReply* src );
```